# Function objects in Haskell compile error

Tags: haskell, function-object

I'm trying to create a class `Func` which represents a function, and then a data type `Dot` which composes functions. Below is my attempt, but I'm getting compile errors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Func where
  class Func f a b | f -> a, f -> b where
    apply :: f -> a -> b

  data Dot f1 f2 where
    Dot :: (Func f1 a b, Func f2 b c) => f1 -> f2 -> Dot f1 f2

  instance Func (Dot f1 f2) a c where
    apply (Dot f1 f2) = (apply f2) . (apply f1)
```

I get the following errors:

```
Func.hs:15:26:
    Could not deduce (Func f2 b c) arising from a use of `apply'
    from the context (Func f1 a1 b, Func f2 b c1)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Dot :: forall f1 f2 a b c.
                        (Func f1 a b, Func f2 b c) =>
                        f1 -> f2 -> Dot f1 f2,
               in an equation for `apply'
      at Func.hs:15:12-20
    Possible fix:
      add (Func f2 b c) to the context of
        the data constructor `Dot'
        or the instance declaration
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(apply f2)'
    In the expression: (apply f2) . (apply f1)
    In an equation for `apply':
        apply (Dot f1 f2) = (apply f2) . (apply f1)

Func.hs:15:39:
    Could not deduce (Func f1 a b) arising from a use of `apply'
    from the context (Func f1 a1 b, Func f2 b c1)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Dot :: forall f1 f2 a b c.
                        (Func f1 a b, Func f2 b c) =>
                        f1 -> f2 -> Dot f1 f2,
               in an equation for `apply'
      at Func.hs:15:12-20
    Possible fix:
      add (Func f1 a b) to the context of
        the data constructor `Dot'
        or the instance declaration
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(apply f1)'
    In the expression: (apply f2) . (apply f1)
    In an equation for `apply':
        apply (Dot f1 f2) = (apply f2) . (apply f1)
```

What do I need to fix to make this compile?

I realise this might seem a bit silly, but I thought it might be useful to be able to carry around different functions as unique types, as one could perhaps attach various metadata to those types (I'm not sure exactly what yet).

Comment: Could you include the errors you get?

Comment: I've now added the errors.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the instance head of `Func (Dot f1 f2) a c` can't "look into" `f1` and `f2` to deduce the functional dependencies. You need to do this yourself, which is much easier with the equivalent formulation

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}

class Func f where
  type FuncArg f :: *
  type FuncRes f :: *
  apply :: f -> FuncArg f -> FuncRes f

data Dot f1 f2 where
  Dot :: (Func f1, Func f2, FuncArg f2~FuncRes f1)
                                 => f1 -> f2 -> Dot f1 f2

instance Func (Dot f1 f2) where
  type FuncArg (Dot f1 f2) = FuncArg f1
  type FuncRes (Dot f1 f2) = FuncRes f2
  apply (Dot f1 f2) = (apply f2) . (apply f1)
```

Or do you have any particular reason to prefer fundeps over type families?

Comment: No reason to prefer fundeps over type families, I'm just learning, so if type families is a better way, I'll try that.

Comment: @Clinton Type families are not a better way in all situations, but here (and in many other situations), I'd say they are preferable.

Comment: Daniel: When are they not preferable? leftaroundabout's suggestion looks quite clean to me. It's a little but more verbose, that's all.

Comment: @Clinton: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies_vs._type_families

Comment: @Clinton I don't remember an example off-hand, but there are some things that (currently, at least) can better be expressed with FunDeps than with type families. At the moment, type families don't work with `OverlappingInstances`, while `FunctionalDependencies` does, so if you need overlapping instances, you haven't the choice.

Comment: There's nothing in the above formulation that restricts `Dot` to only `Func`s with a result where `f1` and `f2` match, and hence I'm getting compile errors. Is there some extra constraints I need to add to `Dot`?

Comment: Worked out the last comment, adding: `FuncRes f1 ~ FuncArg f2` to the context of `Dot` does the trick.

Comment: Of course, I should have mentioned. That's just the direct translation of `(Func f1 a b, Func f2 b c)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Overlapping instances are only *necessary* to do disreputable stuff that (arguably) should violate the fundeps, with `TypeEq` the canonical example. Overlaps should give the same result where they coincide--type families *are* allowed to overlap when syntactically identical, with fundeps GHC will trust you if it can't prove a conflict. Where fundeps really shine is in expressing complicated interdependencies without polluting the namespace or needing a mile-long context full of `~` constraints.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate cause for the errors is that

instance Func (Dot f1 f2) a c where
    apply (Dot f1 f2) = (apply f2) . (apply f1)

says you have an instance for *any* types `a` and `b` with `Dot`, these have nothing to do with the `a` and `b` used for constructing the `Dot`.

Adding the context `(Func f1 a b, Func f2 b c)` to the instance declaration makes it compile with ghc-7.2, but not with 7.4 or 7.6.

Adding the types `a` and `c` as type parameters to `Dot`,

```
data Dot f1 f2 a c where
  Dot :: (Func f1 a b, Func f2 b c) => f1 -> f2 -> Dot f1 f2 a c
```

makes it compile with all those GHCs.

Comment: Do you know why the behavior depends on the GHC version? What changed?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I know that the type-checking changed, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know why the old one was happy with just the constraint.